# The integral transform definition

Tags: functional-analysis

I am hoping someone can show me the algebra behind the following definition.

I was told in my undergraduate degree that the operator equation, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the operator, can be rewritten as such:

$h(x) = \hat{\mathcal{L}} f(x) \to h(x) = \int L(x,x') f(x') dx'  $

If the greens functions ($G(x,x')$) is defined such that
$f(x) = \int G(x,x') h(x')dx'$ can someone show me how $h(x) = \hat{\mathcal{L}} f(x)$ can be rewritten to  $h(x) = \int L(x,x') f(x') dx'$ and hence show what $L(x,x')$ is.

Apologies if this is hard to understand it is my first time asking a question. 
Thanks Dom.

Comment: Is $\hat{\mathcal L}$ an arbitrary bounded operator on $L^2$? And is $L$ supposed to be a function? Consider for example $\hat{\mathcal L} = \mathbb 1$, then you have no function $L$ so that $\int L(x,x') f(x')\,dx'= f(x)$ for all $f\in L^2$.

Comment: To your first answer I think the answer is yes yes. It also assumes the operator has non-zero eigenvalues. To your second point if $\hat{\mathcal{L}} = 1$ then doesn't $L = \delta(x-x')$? Sorry if I am not using proper notation, I'm a physicist by trade. Thanks Dom

Comment: In what context did you learn this statement? What were you studying at the time?

Comment: I was learning about Green's Functions at the time.

Comment: I was learning about Green's Functions at the time. Its looking at inhomogeneous  differential equations and using a basis to show what the greens function is.

Comment: Were you studying ODEs or PDEs? Linear I assume.

Comment: It was arbitrary. Various differential equations were studied.some. Most were ODES and were linear. a few PDE's and again were linear. I can't remember any non linear problems.